# Request POST Using QNetworkReply timeout

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply, qnetworkrequest

I'm using QtCreator based on version 4.8 to develop an application for a device that uses linux with operating system.

I'm trying to make a POST order in QT
I am using the following libraries

```
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
```

I have the following code snippets

```
{
    QString msg;
    QString url = "myURL";
    QNetworkRequest request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url));
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("application/json; charset=UTF-8"));

    QString message = QString("{\"message\" : %1}").arg("\"hello\"");

    QByteArray AliveJson = message.toLatin1();

    reply = manager->post(request, AliveJson);
    
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(finished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void page100::finished(QNetworkReply *r)
{
    qDebug()<<"METOD FINISHED CALLED!";
    QString msg;
    qDebug()<< r;
    qDebug()<< "-----------------------------";
    qDebug()<< reply;
    if (r == reply) {
        int status = r->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
        if (r->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError && status >= 200 && status < 300) {
            msg = QString("successfull reply (%1)").arg(status);//200
            qDebug()<<reply->readAll();
        } else {
            msg = QString("failure reply (%1), %2").arg(status).arg(r->errorString());
            qDebug()<<msg;
        }
        reply = NULL;
    } else {
        msg = QString("unknown reply, url=%1").arg(r->url().toString());
       qDebug()<<msg;
    }
    r->deleteLater();
    ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText() + msg);
    qDebug()<<msg;
}
```

I always get the following error

```
failure reply(0), socket operation timed out
```

I tried to create a new url to communicate but I keep getting the same error.

device is properly connected to the internet. I have already done ping procedures and the device communicates correctly

Comment: Is the url reachable, f.ex using a webbrowser? Have you tried a public url, like `https://stackoverflow.com`, which should at least return a succesfull reply?

Comment: Which OS and Qt version are you using?

Comment: Do GET requests work as expected?

Comment: @m7913d  yes, the url is reachable

I'm using QtCreator to develop an application for an embedded device where the device's operating system is linux, I'm not sure which version

even making a get I have no positive return

Comment: So, this problem is related to an embedded device not being able to access the internet? Is it correctly connected to the internet and does your app has the necessary permissions to access the internet? Please update your question (and title) to include all the relevant information.

Comment: @m7913d  the device is properly connected to the internet.
I have already done ping procedures and the device communicates correctly

Comment: Are you able to make this request using a tool like Postman? Is the request malformed?

Comment: @CameronTinker 
if I use a tool like the postman I can get successful on the requisition